# Want to achieve searching function in django admin page for multiple tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

I am currently working on django 2.0.2 admin page. I have three tables, which are 'metabolites', 'gene' and 'reactions.' The structure of each class is defined as below:

```
class Genes(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Genes'


class Metabolites(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    compartment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    charge = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    formula = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Metabolites'


class Reactions(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    metabolites = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    lower_bound = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    upper_bound = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    gene_reaction_rule = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    subsystem = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Reactions'
```

As you can see, the 'reaction' class also included 'metabolites' component. A typically reaction actually involved more than two metabolites. What I want to do is, create a search field on the admin page(not the page of each class), and when I type in the reaction id, the searching result can display the reaction and all the involved metabolites, and when I type in a metabolites, the searching result can display this metabolite's information and all reactions this metabolites involved.

Is that possible? Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: what you need is a `foreign key`

Comment: But the 'metabolites' data in' Reaction' table is contains more than one metabolites, which I think cannot be a foreign key.
For example, there is reaction in the 'Reaction' table named 'ABC', this reaction contains 3 metabolites, so in the 'metabolite' list, the data is 'A, B, C'.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

This describes the "old school" way of accomplishing this.  This appears to be a use case for django's many to many fields.  I have not run into this need in my project; so, I have not, yet, studied up the many to many capabilities in django.  I recommend reading the django docs for how to use many to many fields.

The way described here will accomplish the desired connections in the data.  However, I suspect that the django admin will be easier and more straightforward to set up using a many to many field.

**end edit**

You want to make another model for `metabolites_in_reaction` that only contains its own primary key, a foreign key to the reaction and foreign key to metabolites.

```
class ReactionMetabolites(models.Model):
    reaction = models.ForeignKey(Reactions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    metabolite = models.ForeignKey(Metabolites, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A many to  many field may  also be appropriate here;  I have not really figured out the many to many fields yet.

**Edit 2:**

After making these changes in your models,  you will need to make and apply migrations to apply the changes to your database.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But another question is where to input the search words? I want to add a search field in the admin-page, but I don't know how. (I mean the admin page, which is 127.0.0.1:8000/admin. Not the page of each table)

Comment: When your models are defined appropriately for the usage you are trying to accomplish, django admin will find the fields and know what to do with them.

Comment: Thanks. But could you please explain the ReactionMetabolites class more specifically? I mean, when you create a new model, there should be a table linked to the 'ReactionMetabolites, which I don't have in my database

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed update! Now I figured it out!

Comment: @HAOYANGMI If the answer solved your problem, then please upvote and/or accept.